# Generic vertex attribute array N uses a pointer with small value(0x0000000000000000)?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl

Getting this output from my OpenGl debug callback everytime glDrawElements is called:

> [OPENGL][SEVERITY_LOW][API][OTHER]Usage warning: Generic vertex
>   attribute array 1 uses a pointer with a small value
>   (0x0000000000000000). Is this intended to be used as an offset into a
>   buffer object?
>
> [OPENGL][SEVERITY_LOW][API][OTHER]Usage warning: Generic vertex
>   attribute array 2 uses a pointer with a small value
>   (0x0000000000000000). Is this intended to be used as an offset into a
>   buffer object?

Code for setting up VAO/VBO:

```
inline void Mesh::CreateMesh(std::vector<int> _indices, std::vector<float> _verts, std::vector<float> _norms, std::vector<float> _texCoords) {
    indices_ = _indices;
    vertices_ = _verts;
    normals_ = _norms;
    texCoords_ = _texCoords;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId_);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId_);

    std::cout << "Mesh::SetupAttribBuffer::Vertex Array Created: " << vaoId_ << std::endl;

    glGenBuffers(1, &indicesVboId_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesVboId_);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_.size() * sizeof(int), indices_.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    std::cout << "Mesh::SetupAttribBuffer::Indices Buffer Created: " << indicesVboId_ << std::endl;

    verticesVboId_ = SetupAttribBuffer(0, 3, vertices_.data());
    //normalsVboId_ = SetupAttribBuffer(1, 3, normals_);
    //texCoordsVboId_ = SetupAttribBuffer(2, 2, texCoords_);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(verticesVboId_);
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalsVboId_);
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordsVboId_);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(indicesVboId_);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

inline int Mesh::SetupAttribBuffer(int _location, int _components, float _data[]) {
    unsigned int bufferId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_data) * sizeof(float), _data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_location, _components, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    std::cout << "Mesh::SetupAttribBuffer::Attribute Buffer Created: " << bufferId << std::endl;

    return bufferId;
}
```

How i am calling glDrawElements:

```
glBindVertexArray(mesh->vaoId_);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->indicesVboId_);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->indicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Even though I am getting the callback output(at top), my mesh(triangle) still manages to get rendered fine. My question is, "Is there something I need to change when setting up my VAO/VBO's to stop those errors? Or should I just make my callback method ignore those types of errors?"

Comment: `glEnableVertexAttribArray(verticesVboId_);`: The parameter should be the location of the attribute in the shader, not the VBO.  `glEnableVertexAttribArray(indicesVboId_);` same, but in addition index buffers are not attributes.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error messages happen because wrong vertex attributes get enabled.

The two lines

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(verticesVboId_);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(indicesVboId_);
```

are wrong because the parameter should specify the location of the attribute in the shader and not a buffer id.